# Error 403 when trying to access Raspberry Pi web page from PC browser

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

I'm working on a project for school and I'm trying to read data from a web page on my raspberry pi and display it on my page on my PC web page. I'm using ajax, but when I try to access the web page on RPi on IP 192.168.1.8 it gives me an: "error 403 forbidden" error so I don't know what to do

my code to get to the page:

```
function AddShoots() {
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://192.168.1.8",
    success: function (html) {
      alert(html);
    },
  });
}
```

error image:
[if it's any help, sorry for the language I'm from Slovenia, so it's Slovene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LFBp.png)

Comment: What web server are you running on your raspi? Have you checked the webserver logs to see why it's responding with a 403?

Comment: Do you get anything back if you go to http://192.168.1.8 in your web browser on your PC?

Comment: Check, if you have the right port. HTTP requests usually go with port 80. Is the webserver on your pi listening to this port?

Comment: @Cully I'm running apache2 the error logs are empty

Comment: @JamieG yeah i get a BOX HTTP server Error 403

Comment: @itzFlubby yeah I think the port 80 is working... at least when I use sudo netstat -pant | grep 80 it shows that its listening

Comment: Are you checking the access logs too? A 403 isn't necessarily an error.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

1. I adjusted IP addresses on my PC and RPi. I have them connected through a straight-through ethernet cable, so I set a static IP on my PC for an ethernet connection and I set static IP on my RPi for eth0.
2. I enabled cross-network sharing in the network settings on PC
3. I enabled headers and added CORS header on apache ([how to enable them on here](https://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html))

Comment: If you are going to answer your own question, provide more information about what exactly you did. Imagine someone has the same problem as you and finds this question. Will your answer help them solve their problem?

Comment: @Cully thanks for your reply I edited my answer I think it's more helpful now.